# I am trying to run an electron application in nodejs which is fetching data from a live server db

Tags: ssl

8020:0131/105418.182:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(995)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100

i want to run the code and display the results without the ssl errors
i want to enable inter process communication between my python, js and html file without the ssl error occuring again when i am using nodejs and electron framework